# How to add Mongodb spark connector without internet and maven

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

If i want use `MongoDB` in spark i should use `spark2-submit --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0 ...`
but this command requires maven and internet

```
manualBookingReservations = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource"
).option("uri",uri
).option("partitioner" , "MongoPaginateBySizePartitioner"
).load()
```

spark2-submit cmd:

```
spark2-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --files /etc/hive \
    /conf/hive-site.xml --executor-cores 1 --driver-cores 1 \
    --num-executors 1 --driver-memory 1G --executor-memory 1G \
    --jars ./mongo-spark-connector_2.11.jar \
     spark-awesome-app.spark2.py
```

* assume that "mongo-spark-connector_2.11.jar" exists on current dir where i do spark2-sumbit

How to add Mongodb spark connector without internet or maven ?

Comment: Download or build Mongo Spark jars, and distribute manually or using `--jars` command.

Comment: I'v tried it, but unfortunately some why it's throws that it's cannot find "DefaultSource" of mongo (looks like it unable to find jar), even i used `--jars` parameter. Do you know how to list available jars from pyspark2

Comment: What is the mode? Did you add jar to driver class path?

Comment: its runs on `Yarn - cluster mode`

Comment: i'v added jar to hdfs and using `Hue` schedule it  and it run with `--jars ./jar.jar`

Comment: Remember that in the cluster mode jar has to be reachable from each node - local path from the node you use for submit won't do.